# Can someone please share powershell if any for SharePoint workspace

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-workspace

Can someone please help me sharing any script to know who are the list of users using actively "Microsoft SharePoint work-space" ?